# r dbWriteTable in loop

Tags: r, rmysql

I have many table that I am saving to a MariaDb in AWS RDS. I can manually save the tables. However I want to create a loop to do and I can't figure out the syntax on the dbWriteTable command. 
    library(RMySQL)

```
dbWriteTable(con, "Account" , Account, overwrite = T)
dbWriteTable(con, "Campaign",  Campaign, overwrite = T)
dbWriteTable(con, "Contact" , Contact, overwrite = T)
dbWriteTable(con, "User", User, overwrite =T)
```

Instead I would like to do it in a loop.

```
nm = c("Account", "Campaign", "Contact",  "User")

for (i in 1:length(nm)) {

  dbWriteTable(con,  nm[i], paste(nm[i]), overwrite = TRUE)
 }
```

Comment: Try `get(nm[i])` instead of `paste`.

Comment: I get an Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
  external pointer is not valid.  I have found that the dbWriteTable is finicky

Comment: for some reason get0() will work but get() does not work.  Thanks for the tip

Comment: Interesting @Spruce Island, glad I could help. Mind if I post as an answer?

Comment: No please do.  Thanks you saved me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per comments above, using `get0` instead of `paste` like so will work:

```
nm = c("Account", "Campaign", "Contact",  "User")

for (i in 1:length(nm)) {
    dbWriteTable(con,  nm[i], get0(nm[i]), overwrite = TRUE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
for (i in nm){
  dbWriteTable(con,  i, paste(i), overwrite = TRUE)
}
```

You do not need to extract the i from the original list with brackets, because i represents directly that object in the list. Essentially you are saying for each instance in nm, write to the db table named i (which will be one of the words in your list) and paste the value of i as the name.

Comment: I get the error.  Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file 'Account': No such file or directory. Its like the data.frame can't be found.. I have tried so many different things...

Comment: Sorry it was of no help. Because I did not have the files to over-write I could not test. I ran the loop with prints and returns. But that sounds like a working directory directory issue...maybe `setwd(" your/directory/here")`